# Haskell: when to use type class and when to use concrete type?

Tags: haskell, inheritance, int, typeclass

When declaring functions, we could either use type class or concrete type(Am I right?) So I can use "Num" as type indicator or "Int". I'm not sure if "Int" has any definition out of "Num"? Can I define my own concrete type that "inherit" from "Num"?

I ask this question from java/C# inheritance perspective, just begin with Haskell. Would you give some hints?

Comment: I believe the sort of type class usage you are describing is used for the sake of polymorphism, not for inheritance-like behavior. So, if you write a function and you only ever care about using it on `Int` data, there is no need to rope in the type class `Num`. But if you want to write a function that works for many different types of data, you can qualify the type with the type class constraint.

Answer (score 7):

From the OO perspective, a type class is something like an interface or a [trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29). In Haskell you generally use concrete types when you require a certain structure of the datatype (because you will unpack it), and a type class when you just want a certain behavior. For example, you can write

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x y = x + y
```

but you do not use the internal structure of `Int`s here; you just need something that supports addition, which is [`Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) (note that it has a `(+)` in method list):

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x + y
```

And yes, of course, you can declare that your own class supports the `Num` interface. Look at the link above, there is a list of methods called "minimal complete definition". This is what other functions that use it will rely on. In a pinch, you may explicitly set some methods to `undefined`, but you'll get a runtime error if someone tries to call them:

```
data MyData = MyData Int Int

instance Num MyData where
    (MyData x1 y1) + (MyData x2 y2) = MyData (x1 + y1) (x2 + y2)
    (*) = undefined
    ...
```

See how you use your knowledge of `MyData` structure to abstract possible users of your class from it? If they want to add two values of this type together, they do not need to know how the data is arranged inside, they just need to know that it is an instance of `Num`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Daniel, I don't know why I called the type that. Must be all this talk about OO.

Comment: Why can MyData be defined to use it self in "data MyData = MyData Int Int"?

Comment: These are different entities. Yes, they use the same name, but they never occur in the same context, so the compiler can always distinguish them. The left `MyData` is a type, the right one is a constructor (essentially, a function with the signature `Int -> Int -> MyData`). I could have used any other name for the constructor, but in most cases it is best to use the same name if there is only one constructor (to make reading the program easier).